Why do the Java code templates in Eclipse ignore Git variables?
We have configured Eclipse to add the Git user name to a type's Javadoc.
Something like:
     /**
      * ${todo}.
      *
      * <p>Copyright (c) ${year}, Foobar Ltd.</p>
      * @author ${name:git_config(user.name)}
      * ${tags}
      */

We're using Eclipse 2023-12, and a couple of versions ago, this stopped working. As soon as I restarted Eclipse, this template was gone. I could re-import it, and then it worked as long as Eclipse was running. But after a restart, it was again gone.
I experimented a bit and found out that the code template is correctly saved in org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs (and I can also export it correctly to an XML file), but at the next start, it's completely ignored. The file still contains that Git variable, though.
So, can someone tell me why this stopped working? Especially since Eclipse makes exactly this suggestion when I want to insert a variable while editing a code template.

Your template not being saved, on its own, sounds like a potential regression to report to github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui/issues

Ah, looks like this was already created more than two years ago: https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui/issues/180
